# Extract data between double quotation in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the text and i would like to return just the data in double quotation in Sql.

Input -

```
Task "Testing Data" started successfully.
```

Output:

```
Testing Data
```

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server`

Answer (score 2):

Try like following.

```
DECLARE @testData VARCHAR(100) = 'Task : "Testing Data" started successfully.' 

SELECT Substring(@testData, Charindex('"', @testData, 1) + 1, 
              Len(@testData) - Charindex('"', @testData) - 
              Charindex('"', Reverse(@testData))) AS [Output];
```

**Output**

```
+--------------+
| Output       |
+--------------+
| Testing Data |
+--------------+
```

Comment: I m getting this error message : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Check this http://rextester.com/DQAN82211

Comment: Works for me in SQL Server, what string are you passing in?

Comment: This implies the OP has data they're using this against that doesn't have enough "s. @Skenneth is this true?

Comment: This worked for me. I had to remove some data to get this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**MYsql**

```
SELECT replace(SUBSTRING_INDEX
('"Testing Data" started successfully.', '"', 2),'"','')
```

**SQLServer**

```
select replace(substring(@string,1,charindex('"',@string,2)),'"','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(100) = 'Task : "Testing Data" started successfully.'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text,CHARINDEX('"',@Text)+1, CHARINDEX('"',@Text,CHARINDEX('"',@Text)+1)-CHARINDEX('"',@Text)-1)
```

Comment: Error Message : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: SKenneth: The code snippets works with SQL Server 2016 version. May I get which version of SQL you are running the script against?

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2016. This query worked for me. I had data which didn't end with " that caused the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in mySQL:

```
set @myVar = 'Task : "Testing Data" started successfully';
select substring_index(substring_index(@myVar, '"', -2),'"',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `MS SQL SERVER` -

I have use `substring`, `charindex`, `patindex` and `iif` functions to resolve this case. Please find my query below -

```
declare @tmp_tbl table (id int identity, Some_string nvarchar(1000))

insert into @tmp_tbl (Some_string)
select '"Testing Data" example' union all
select 'Test data "Testing Data"' union all
select 'Test "Testing Data" example' union all
select 'Test example' union all
select 'Test " example' union all
select 'Test "" example' union all
select 'Test "Testing Data" example "Testing 123 '

select
    id,
    iif(
        patindex('%"%"%', Some_string) = 0,
        NULL,
        substring(
            Some_string,
            (charindex('"', Some_string) + 1),
            charindex('"', Some_string, charindex('"', Some_string) + 1) - charindex('"', Some_string) - 1
        )
    )
from
    @tmp_tbl
```